# Drupal printing .info script groups separately

Tags: javascript, drupal, themes

I'm defining my scripts in my theme's .info in 2 groups; those loading pre-body and those loading post file like this:

```
; Scripts in head group to load pre-body
scripts[head][] = js/cufon.js
scripts[head][] = js/font.js

; Scripts in end group to load after all other html
scripts[end][] = js/scripts.js
```

Is there any way to print these out separately in my view? I assumed I would be abble to do it like this:

```
<?php print $scripts['head']; ?>
<!-- html -->
<?php print $scripts['end']; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I checked all vars in scope and can't find anything that suggests the scripts are passed through to the view in groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell what I was trying to do is not possible but it can be done another way.

Create a [theme]_preprocess_html function in your template.php and use drupal_add_js to add your scripts with a scope then use drupal_get_js to retrieve all scripts added to each scope and as to $vars:

```
// Set Scripts
$path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'themename');
// pre-body scripts
$options = array('scope'=>'scripts_head','preprocess'=>true);
drupal_add_js($path.'/js/cufon.js',$options);
drupal_add_js($path.'/js/myfont.font.js',$options);
// post-body scripts
$options['scope'] = 'header';
drupal_add_js($path.'/js/scripts.js',$options);
// pass to view
$vars["scripts_head"] = drupal_get_js('scripts_head');
$vars["scripts_end"]  = drupal_get_js('header');
```

Documentation:
[drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)
[drupal_get_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/7)